# Add a custom title to Shiny app with Plotly charts

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the following Shiny application the displays a time series line chart using Plotly with 5 drop down options.  This works but I would like to add a custom title somewhere around the top of each selection.  Is there an easy way to add to this application, and if so where should I add it?

```
#Import libraries
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(bindrcpp)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
              label = "Select Data:",
              choices = c("Distinct_FLD","Not_On_MM","API_Call_Count","Cost","CACHE_Count"),

              selected = "Distinct_FLD"),

  plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "600px")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  #Import data
  df = read.csv("API_Statistics.csv")  

  output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

    if (input$n_breaks == "Distinct_FLD") {
      #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
      x <- df$Date[!is.na(df$Distinct_FLD)]
      #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
      y <- df$Distinct_FLD[!is.na(df$Distinct_FLD)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "Not_On_MM") {
      #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
      x <- df$Date[!is.na(df$Not_On_MM)]
      #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
      y <- df$Not_On_MM[!is.na(df$Not_On_MM)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "API_Call_Count") {
      #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
      x <- df$Date[!is.na(df$API_Call_Count)]
      #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
      y <- df$API_Call_Count[!is.na(df$API_Call_Count)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
    } 
    else if (input$n_breaks == "Cost") {
      #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
      x <- df$Date[!is.na(df$Cost)]
      #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
      y <- df$Cost[!is.na(df$Cost)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "CACHE_Count") {
      #Create variable X getting rid of NA values
      x <- df$Date[!is.na(df$CACHE_Count)]
      #Create variable Y getting rid of NA values
      y <- df$CACHE_Count[!is.na(df$CACHE_Count)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  
    }
  })   
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there an easy way to add a custom title to each chart in this application, and if so where should I add it?

Comment: You are dynamically (reactivity) creating these plots, meaning using a html  tag in the ui will most likely not work. Maybe what you should do is dynamically create a title for each graph (possibly under the respective "`if` statement) and output that using `renderText` to a corresponding `h_(textOutput("Title"))`. That way when the graph changes, the `renderText` function will be able to dynamically create a new title and output it to the UI. Note the `textOutput` can be placed directly above the `plotlyOutput`

Comment: I will try that @Chabo

Comment: Another option would be to define the title directly in the chart using `plot_ly(your_code) %>%
  layout(title = "myTitle")`. See [this](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with:

```
h_(textOutput("Title"))
```